# How to save currently logged in user username in model's field while saving a form?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-users

I am using CreateView.

**view.py file**

```
class AdvertismentCreate(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Advertisment  
    form_class = AdvertismentForm
```

**Advertisment_form.html file**

```
{% extends 'app/layout.html' %}
{%load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
     <form method="post">
         {% csrf_token %}
         {% crispy form %}     

     </form>     

{% endblock %}
```

**Model.py file**

```
class Users(models.Model):
    Id = models.CharField(max_length = 20,primary_key =True)

class Advertisment(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    edition = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    year = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 2000)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    contact = models.IntegerField()
    User_ID = models.ForeignKey(Users) 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('advertisments_detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Comment: Can you show your `AdvertisementForm`?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set it in your view

something like:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save(commit=false)
    form.cleaned_data['user_id'] = request.user.id
    form.save()
```